# Scraping image from research gate profile in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to download the person's image present on research gate in python. I am using selenium for it because all other methods give 403 at the initial request hit (I tried changing headers but am still getting 403).

Selenium is working fine and this is how I am doing it right now:

```
from selenium import webdriver

URL="https://www.researchgate.net/profile/xyz"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    options=options
)

x=driver.get(URL)

# Find all image elements on the page
image_elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('img') # get 2 elements here only

# Download and save each image
for i, image_element in enumerate(image_elements):
    # Get the source URL of the image
    image_url = image_element.get_attribute('src')
    print(image_url)
    print(type(image_url))
    
    # Skip images without a valid URL
    if not image_url or 'http' not in image_url:
        continue
    
    # Send an HTTP GET request to download the image content
    response = requests.get(image_url, stream=True)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        # Generate a unique filename for each image
        image_name = f'image_{i}.jpg'
        image_path = os.path.join(folder, image_name)
        
        # Save the image to the specified folder
        with open(image_path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(response.content)
        
        print(f"Downloaded image: {image_path}")
    else:
        print(f"Failed to download image: {image_url}")
```

The issue is that for the profile having an image, I am only getting 2 links and neither of them have the profile photo's link. How can I get the link of the jpg or png photo and can then download it with selenium from research gate?
Any help will be highly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the basic way to extract the profile image. I used `urlparse` to get the image filename from the `src`.

```
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urlparse
import selenium.common.exceptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
chrome_options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')

# disable the banner "Chrome is being controlled by automated test software"
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])

driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver',options=chrome_options)

driver.get('https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Ahmad-Ashrif-A-Bakar-2')
try:
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
    image_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "nova-legacy-e-avatar__img")))
    if image_element:
        image_url = driver.find_element_by_class_name('nova-legacy-e-avatar__img')
        image_name = urlparse(image_url.get_attribute("src"), scheme='', allow_fragments=True).path.split('/')[-1]
        with open(image_name, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(image_url.screenshot_as_png)
       
except selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException as e:
    print(e)

sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the answer! I am getting this error however while running your code exactly. NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".nova-legacy-e-avatar__img"}.
Can you please suggest a workaround it?

Comment: You are getting this error when you run the exact code that I posted?

Comment: yes, for the exact code. My selenium version is 3.8.1.

Comment: I added some `WebDriverWait` code to my answer, which might help you.  This code works correctly on my system using the same version of `selenium`

Comment: it still doesn't work. Is there any other solution besides selenium? I am getting 403 from newspaper3k, requests, etc.

Comment: where did the newspaper3k and requests 403 come from?

Comment: Your profile says that you are located in Pakistan.  If that this correct, you might have to use a proxy for some website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253634/discussion-between-life-is-complex-and-asim).